# how to properly set the orientation of Table layout in android

Tags: android

Following is my code along with the xml file i have 2 table layouts within 2 frame layouts. the 1st table layout is used to set the heading for the table while the 2nd table is used to set the rows dynamically in the 2nd table layout though the heading seems to be fitting perfectly the rows dont align properly  below the heading  may be i am doing some mistake in setting parameters for the table layout . I am in a fix . Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
package com.table;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.YuvImage;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;





public class TableActivity extends Activity 
{
    TableLayout table,table_values;
    Button scan,add;
    String value;



    EditText ed1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        createTableLayout(); 
        addrows();


        scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.read);
        if(scan != null) 
        {
            scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) 
                {

                }
            });
        }








        try 
        {
            scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                   setContentView(R.layout.code);
                    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {


                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }








    }




    public void createTableLayout()
     {
            table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
          //  table.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sky);
            //TableRow tr_heading = new TableRow(this);
            table_values = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout2);
            TableRow tr_heading = new TableRow(this);
            tr_heading.setId(10);
            tr_heading.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            tr_heading.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));



            TextView Serial = new TextView(this);
            Serial.setId(20);
            Serial.setText("Sr No.   ");
            Serial.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr_heading.addView(Serial); // add the column to the table row








            //TextView label_question = new TextView(this);
            TextView Name = new TextView(this);
            Name.setId(20);
            Name.setText("ID        ");
            Name.setWidth(40);
            Name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr_heading.addView(Name); // add the column to the table row

            //TextView label_question = new TextView(this);
            TextView Quantity = new TextView(this);
            Quantity.setId(20);
            Quantity.setText("                             Quantity");
            Quantity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr_heading.addView(Quantity); // add the column to the table row


            TextView amt = new TextView(this);
            amt.setId(20);
            amt.setText("            Amt");
            amt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr_heading.addView(amt); 


            table.addView(tr_heading, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

     }   


            //--------------------------Adding Rows to your Table --------------------------------------

        public void addrows()
            {

                            Integer count = 0;
                            for (int count1 = 0; count1<3; count1++)
                             { 


                                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                                if (count % 2 != 0)
                                tr.setId(100 + count);
                                tr.setClickable(true);

                                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                                TextView sr = new TextView(this);
                                sr.setText("1");
                                //sr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER );
                                sr.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                                sr.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                sr.setClickable(true);
                                tr.addView(sr);








                                TextView idval = new TextView(this);

                                idval.setText(value);
                                idval.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER );
                                idval.setText("             fdfj");
                                idval.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);

                                idval.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                idval.setClickable(true);
                                tr.addView(idval);


                                EditText quantity = new EditText(this);
                                //quantity.setId(200 + count);
                                quantity.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER );
                                quantity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        //      quantity.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        //      quantity.setWidth(1);
                                quantity.setText("1");
                                quantity.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                                int val=Integer.parseInt((quantity.getText().toString()));
                        //      quantity.setHeight(2);
                                quantity.setEnabled(true);
                                quantity.setPadding(2,0,5,0);
                                tr.addView(quantity);


                                TextView amount=new TextView(this);
                                amount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                amount.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                amount.setClickable(true);
                                //amount.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                amount.setEnabled(true);
                                //amount.setText("             1000");
                                amount.setText(String.valueOf((    val*10)));
                        //      amount.setWidth(1);
                        //      amount.setHeight(2);
                                tr.addView(amount);


                                // finally add this to the table row
                                table_values.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                count++;



                             }
            }




}



     **Xml file is below:
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TableLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
           </TableLayout>
    <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout4" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <TableLayout 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TableLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button 
            android:text="Scan" 
            android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button"  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </Button>

    </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>


screen shot:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nqsR.png 


![This is ther screen image[1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nqsR.png
```

Comment: what is the expected result? can you please put a sketch of what you wish to do ? it's hard to imagine what you want to do by what you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 framelayouts , so they overlap each other since they are not given anything that makes them to be on beneath the other.

anyway , i would recommend to use a single tableLayout , or a listView , or a gridLayout .

here's an example of a tableLayout:

http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/dynamic-tablelayout-in-android/

Comment: I want the edit text field to be placed below the Quantity field in heading .As u can see it is placed close to id along with the vakue 10 . value 10 must come below the amount field